# positioning of a span below an image using css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want the `byline` to appear just below the image.

I am trying to use the `right`, `left`, etc properties in relation to the `relative` property, but the span moves left of the image.

What is the mistake in my code?

```
<section id="manchanabele">
    <img id="club" alt="club" src="images/club.jpg">
    <p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <span id="byline">by: Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </p>    
</section>

section#manchanabele {
    background: #C8C8C8;
}

#club {
    float: right;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}

p#lorem {
    background: #A0A0A0;
}

span#byline {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/S5w7e/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are structuring your DOM in a wrong way, you should wrap the elements you want to float in a single container. I will provide you the code which will result you in something like below

[image]

---

Here, in the code below, I will explain you related to the image above, the black border container is `.wrap`, the one which is having green border is the paragraph, which is `p`, the red on is the container which you are floating to the right which is `.right_float` and the nested elements inside red element is your `img` and `span` respectively.

For example

```
<div class="wrap">
   <p>Hello</p>
   <div class="right_float">
      <img src="#" />
      <span>Hello</span>
   </div>
</div>

.wrap {
   overflow: hidden; /* Clears float */
}

.wrap p {
   float: left;
   width: /*Some fixed width*/
}

.wrap .right_float {
   float: right;
   width: /* Some fixed width */
}

.wrap .right_float span {
   display: block;
}
```

---

Note, if you don't care about the older versions, especially IE, I would recommend you to use a self clearing parent class

```
.clear:after {
   clear: both;
   display: table;
   content: "";
}
```

Now, you can call the above class on your parent element holding floated elements, and you don't have to use `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the byline aligned with the image by wrapping the elements in a container such as a DIV.

HTML:

```
<section id="manchanabele">
    <div id="align">
         <img id="club" alt="club" src="images/club.jpg">
         <span id="byline">by: Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </div>
    <p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
section#manchanabele {
    background: #C8C8C8;
}

#align {
    float:right;
    width:75px;
}

#club {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}

p#lorem {
    background: #A0A0A0;
}
```

N.B. You may want to consider using classes rather the IDs if you need to use this layout several times for similar content.

Answer (score 1):

Use this markup:

```
<article>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/70/70" alt="a random image" class="thumb" >
        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over all the messy markup and writes a new one.</p>
    </div>
    <footer>By The Fox</footer>
</article>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5GkH/1/

or if you need the image and the byline always one below the other keeping a blank sidebar on the right follow the advice of @Mr. Alien

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear:both; after the image.

Like so

```
<section id="manchanabele">
        <img id="club" alt="club" src="images/club.jpg">
        <div style="clear:both;></div>

        <p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        <span id="byline">by: Lorem Ipsum</span>
        </p>

    </section>
```

Also avoid floating inline elements. Better if you wrapped that image with a div and then floated the div.

Comment: No, I don't understand. Where should I add this div? What should I wrap within a div?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Put the div with a style of clear:both; after the floated image. Clear:both; forces everything after a floated element to go below it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I want the paragraph to float left of the image and the "by: lorem ipsum" to go below the image.

Comment: Then float both the image and the paragraph to the left and then insert the div with the clear:both; after the paragraph.